# Apache Spark pool accruing cost even when paused?

Tags: apache-synapse

Hi I thought if I paused the pool, it wouldn't cost anything, but in less than 24 hours, it's gone from 0 to £3 with absolutely nothing running and Cost Analysis says it was all Synapse workspace. Built-in serverless pool has been online all this while but I don't think it costs unless we run queries?

I've set up the account just to practice as opposed to any real life use.